# duplicating blocks of code inside conditional

Tags: angular

The ask:
A second type of label-with-tooltips. The existing label has its tooltip flush RIGHT; the new one has tooltip butted up left against END of the label.

The given:
The existing labels are widespread. I do not wish to *change* any of the working ones. I wish to only *add* things to make this *new* type work. So, even though there might be a better way to mark up the HTML, I don't wish to go back and touch any that I don't need to.

Here is a label with tooltip of the default type (float far right):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <app-label 
        labelText="My Default Label"
        tooltip="Tooltip is flush far right"
        bold="true">
    </app-label>
</div>
```

It calls this component:

```
<app-tooltip [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
<b>
    <label>
        <span *ngIf="error" class="icon-error"></span>
        <span *ngIf="bold">
            <b>{{labelText}}</b>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="!bold">
            {{labelText}}
        </span>
    </label>
</b>
```

Note that the app-tooltip markup is before the label. The tooltip will be "float: right" - to the far right of the label.

Now... to make my *new* label-with-tooltip (butt against text), I need to set a flag: flushToText:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
    <app-label 
        labelText="My New Label"
        tooltip="Tooltip is flush against text end"
        flushToText="true" <!-- here -->
        bold="true">
    </app-label>
</div>
```

Now I'll modify the label/tip as needed. I'm testing for the flag, then building the entire label and tooltip from scratch, one of two ways, depending on it:

```
  <span *ngIf="!flushToText">
    <app-tooltip [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
    <b>
        <label>
            <span *ngIf="error" class="icon-error"></span>
            <span *ngIf="bold">
                <b>{{labelText}}</b>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!bold">
                {{labelText}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </b>
</span>

<span *ngIf="flushToText">
    <b>
        <label>
            <span *ngIf="error" class="icon-error"></span>
            <span *ngIf="bold">
                <b>{{labelText}}</b>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!bold">
                {{labelText}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </b>
    <app-tooltip flushToText="true" [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
</span>
```

Here is my question. Is there a more efficient way of altering the code than duplicating the entire block and putting one inside a flag=true and another inside a flag=false?

Comment: the position of app-tooltip should be controlled by css, not by relative position in html. that way, you can easily apply css to it based on flushToText flag.

Comment: I agree. Alas, I am stuck with the markup I have, and I haven't found any CSS that will *reliably*. alter it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding `flushToText` to the surrounding `<span>`, you can instead bind it directly to `<app-tooltip>` so then you can conditionally decide which to render.

```
<span>
    <app-tooltip *ngIf="!flushToText" [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
    <b>
        <label>
            <span *ngIf="error" class="icon-error"></span>
            <span *ngIf="bold">
                <b>{{labelText}}</b>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!bold">
                {{labelText}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </b>
    <app-tooltip *ngIf="flushToText" flushToText="true" [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
</span>
```

Comment: I like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could add both tooltips and `*ngIf` them

```
<span>
    <app-tooltip *ngIf="!flushToText" [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
    <b>
        <label>
            <span *ngIf="error" class="icon-error"></span>
            <span *ngIf="bold">
                <b>{{labelText}}</b>
            </span>
            <span *ngIf="!bold">
                {{labelText}}
            </span>
        </label>
    </b>
    <app-tooltip *ngIf="flushToText" flushToText="true" [id]="id" [tooltip]="tooltip"></app-tooltip>
</span>
```

Comment: User 5842 beat ya to it by less than an hour. But thanks. :)